# How long is a google analytics session? Exceeded maximum hits per session, aborting hit

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a Chrome extension and I ran a debug on my analytics code producing a console message of "Exceeded maximum hits per session, aborting hit". Note that this only happens in production.

I understand why this is happening as there is a limit of about 500 utm requests per session.  However, when do these sessions expire? And is there a way to force the session or sessions to expire? I just need to expire these sessions once after an update that resolved some issues.

As the app was experiencing a bug that caused an "over-generating of events" I have resolved this issue and I want to expire all these sessions or know when they will expire.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-XXXXXX-X]":  ssl.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js:18
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ssl.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js:18
Track Pageview ssl.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js:18
Exceeded maximum hits per session. Aborting hit.
```

Comment: Sessions are probably cookie based. But any way you come up with to expire sessions and get more events is likely to violate the ToS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I don't think the 500 requests per session limit should be reached. Maybe your website is over-generating events.

Here are some clues on what could be generating so many events:

> Events Per Session Limit
>
> For each visit (user session), a maximum of approximately 500 combined
>   GATC requests (both events and page views) can be tracked. Keep this
>   in mind when programmatically generating events. Note that—as the
>   number of events in a session approaches the limit—additional events
>   might not be tracked. For example, you should:
>
> - avoid scripting a video to send an event for every second played and
>     other highly repetitive event triggers
> - avoid excessive mouse movement tracking
> - avoid time-lapse mechanisms that generate high event counts

(from Google Analytic's [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide))

And based on the following it appears that a visit lasts from the beginning of the month to the end of the month:

> In order to understand how the Count of visits dimension works, it
>   helps first to understand how sessions are counted in Analytics. Each
>   time a user visits your site, there is a counter applied to their
>   visit that increments with each new session by that visitor. For
>   example, if Visitor A visits your site for the first time in January,
>   their session count is 1. If that visitor then returns in February,
>   their session count will be 2, and so on for each subsequent visit.

(Based on more background information on sessions, see the Google Analytics [Help Center on this topic](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032796))

And maybe you could consider changing the [session timeout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSessionCookieTimeout).

Comment: Note that the manual sessions link you posted is for the iOS SDK. I don't think a similar thing exists for JavaScript.

Comment: Indeed the app was experiencing a bug that caused an "over-generating of events" I have resolved this issue and I just want to expire all these sessions that have reached their limits. Thats kind of vague "For each visit (user session)," I will try to clear cookies. Also, I might try to apply a patch to the app that uses your Managing Sessions link. I will confirm if it works.